# Retrieve original documents originally saved using OLEContainer in VB6

Tags: vb6, ole, vb6-migration

My company is in the process of converting a very large VB6 application to WPF. Throughout the years, customers have saved all different types of documents using the OLEContainer object in VB6. So customers do not lose their documents, I am in need of pulling all those original documents back out and printing them to PDF. I am in need of an automated way to do this. I have been searching for days now and have gotten no where fast. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try to make several smaller and more specific questions. Ideally, start to do something and show your unfortunate (or fortunate, but not completed) solutions